# Missing bundle entity, entity type block_content_type, entity id basic

Tags: 8

I have updated one of my D8 sites to the latest stable version - 8.3.1 using `drush up`. When applying the database update, the update fails with the following error message:

> Failed: LogicException: Missing bundle entity, entity type block_content_type, entity id basic. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityType->getBundleConfigDependency() (line 882 of /var/www/sitename/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityType.php).

This has only happened on 1 site, so it's possibly a config issue specific to the site.

How do I manually create the missing bundle entity?

Comment: Sounds like you have configuration (e.g. form/view displays) that reference the non-existing basic block content type bundle. Export your configuration, search for basic and then probably delete and re-import that config.

Comment: Yes I remember testing some form config then I uninstalled the yaml form module so it looks some config is still there. I will have a look and try the suggestion but that should work. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get passed this error I deleted some rows in the config table:

```
delete from config where name in ('block_content.type.basic', core.entity_view_display.block_content.basic.default', field.field.block_content.basic.body');
```

Comment: When I issued `drupal module:install <module>` I was getting the following error: `[ERROR] Missing bundle entity, entity type media_bundle, entity id file.` Basing on the answer above I deleted the related config with `drupal config:delete active` to continue: `media.type.file`

Comment: The comment below is a ugly workaround.